# The field you are trying to update may be read only error while adding item to list programmatically

Tags: 2010, list, error, splistitem, read-only

I am adding a list item in from an application page which is redirected from web part page.

My code is :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SPSite site = new SPSite("http://bipc11:1234/sites/webparts");
        SPWeb web = site.RootWeb;
        web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
        SPUser currentUser = web.CurrentUser;
        SPList list = web.Lists["Cart"];
        SPListItem item = list.AddItem();
        item["Picture"] = Request.QueryString["title"];
        Response.Write("<script> alert('Pictrue Updated')</script>");
        item["User"] = currentUser;
        Response.Write("<script> alert('User Updated')</script>");
        item.Update();
        Response.Write("<script> alert('Item Updated')</script>");
        web.Update();
        web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
        Response.Write("<script> alert('Value Added To Cart Successfully')</script>");
        Response.Redirect(Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUrlUtility.CombineUrl(web.Url, "/SiteAssets/WebPartPage.aspx"));

    }
```

Here field `Picture` is of type look up in `Cart` list. `User` is the type of person or group. Java script to redirect to the application page is:

```
function myfunction(title)
     {
        window.location.assign("http://bipc11:1234/sites/webparts/_layouts/AddValueToCartList/AddValueToCartList.aspx?title="+title);
     }
```

When the page is redirected to the application page I am getting above mentioned error.

What am I missing? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am unable to find the exact reason for the error:
However pls go through the following points:

1) How to update a Readonly field.

First set Readonly to false and update the field and then revert it back as:

```
Field.ReadOnlyField = false;
Field.Update();
```

2) Updating the Lookupfield:

```
new SPFieldLookupValue(1, "ASP.Net");
```

Comment: I made the changes as per your suggestion: `SPList list = web.Lists["Cart"];list.Fields["User"].ReadOnlyField = false;list.Fields["Picture"].ReadOnlyField = false;SPListItem item = list.AddItem();item["Picture"] = Request.QueryString["title"];item["User"] = new SPFieldLookupValue(Request.QueryString["title"]);item.Update();`

Comment: Now, error is dipslaying, `Value does not fall within the expected range.` at line `item["User"]=new SPFieldLookupValue(Request.QueryString["title"]);`

Comment: is it the same error ? why don't u test each field at one time. It will save and ur time and will help find the problem.

Comment: No I debugged the program and started displaying error at mentioned line.

Comment: Browser displays the error "an unexpected error has occurred"

Comment: ok...u simply try to update one field at a time.

Comment: OK sir, I am trying

Comment: I did it.. but not working

Comment: pls share the code what u are trying...and also the span of the List with content type details.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10672/discussion-between-pushpendra-and-users1100)